# Is it true that $a^{360m + 1} + b^{360n + 1} \equiv 0 (\mod 475) \Leftrightarrow a + b \equiv 0 (\mod 475)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Is it true that $a^{360m + 1} + b^{360n + 1} \equiv 0 (\mod 475) \Leftrightarrow a + b \equiv 0 (\mod 475)$?

It is obvious that we only need to check if $a + b \equiv 0 (\mod 475)$ implied $a^{360m + 1} + b^{360n + 1} \equiv 0 (\mod 475)$ or not.

With the notice that $360 = \varphi (475)$, we are done with the case $(a,475) = 1$ (which leads to $(b,475) = 1$).

But when dealing with the case $(a,475) = 5$, I have some doubt. In this case, $a = 5k$, $b = 5l$ where $(k,5) = 1$, $(l,5) = 1$. A counter-example where $a + b \equiv 0 (\mod 25)$ but $a^{360m + 1} + b^{360n + 1} \not\equiv 0 (\mod 25)$ could have existed.

I'm not sure how to proceed as I don't even know if the statement itself was true at the beginning. Please give me some hint. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the first direction obvious? If you're using Fermat's little theorem then doesn't it just work the other way as well? I don't see the issue.

Comment: I use this: $a^{2k+1}+ b^{2k+1} = (a+b) .(...)$

Comment: And for further comment, $475$ is not a prime for you to use Fermat's little theorem. I'm using Euler's theorem for the case $(a,475) = 1$. But when $(a,475) > 1$, Euler's theorem can't be used.

Comment: I see. Well the general Fermat's little theorem says $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, and so $a^{\varphi(n) + 1} \equiv a \pmod{n}$. Then the claim easily follows.

Comment: If $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$, then $$a^{360m+1}+b^{360m+1}\equiv a^{360m+1}+(-a)^{360m+1}\equiv a^{360m+1}+(-1)^{360m+1}a^{360m+1}\equiv a^{360m+1}-a^{360m+1}\equiv 0\pmod{n}.$$  You seem to have the wrong idea about which implication is trivial, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You can see that $(5k)^{360} ≡5^{\frac{360}{k}}\mod 475$, So $(5k)^{360}-(5l)^{360} ≡0\mod 475$.

Comment: Isn't $a = b = 5 \cdot 19$ a clear counterexample?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter You're right. ElementX and saulspatz showed two methods to show one direction. The other direction works for $(a, 475) = (b, 475) = 1$ by Fermat but not in general as you pointed out.